# sudo: nginx : command not found

Tags: sudo, nginx

I've sshed to a remote vm and have built nginx from source and it works fine.

nginx installation path is `/usr/local/nignx/sbin` which has been added to both `/home/my-username/.bash_profile` and `/root/.bash_profile`; I've logged out `sudo pkill -u $USER` and ssh connected again.

so far I have 
`bochen> which nginx` returns `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx`

`sudo -i` then `root# which nginx` returns: `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx`

but `bochen> sudo nginx` return `command not found`

I don't understand what is going on...

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l`, please.

Comment: got the answer. seems already been asked & anwsered
https://stackoverflow.com/a/257666/6560291